# Automatic mySQLi HTML Table Value Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to be able refresh the values in a HTML table (retrieved from SQL Database), without reloading the page. I want this to be done without a button that needs to be pressed.

```
<div id="display" class="myCustom1">
       <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will call refreshPartial every 5 seconds
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 5000)

});

// calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "data.php", //where the table is
    dataType: 'script',
    format: 'js'
 })
}
</script>
    </div>
```

This is currently what I have, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you're actually getting data back?

Comment: You need to update the target table after AJAX request will be successfully completed. Use 'success` [AJAX event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) to run a script what updetes your table with response's data.

Comment: @Difster Yes I get data back

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you dont have the "success"

```
function refreshPartial() {
$.ajax({
url: "data.php", //where you process the data
dataType: 'script',
format: 'js',
success: function(data)
{
$("#idOfElementWhereYouWantToPutTheData").html(data);
}

})
}
```

and also the "url" is where you process your data not where you get the data